# Reflectively call constructor which throws an exception

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to create an instance of `System.RuntimeType` which has a very annoying constructor:

```
internal class RuntimeType
{
    internal RuntimeType()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Normally you could just try/catch it and the object will have been constructed, even though the exception was thrown. However, being `internal`, I have to use reflection to call these, and the exception will get wrapped into a `TargetInvocationException` and the object thrown away:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Application.Util.Constructor.RuntimeType() in C:\Work\Application\src\Application\Util\Constructor.cs:line 300
   at Tests._4._5.Util.ConstructorTests.RuntimeType() in C:\Work\Application\src\Tests\Tests.4.5\Util\ConstructorTests.cs:line 159
--NotSupportedException
   at System.RuntimeType..ctor()
```

`System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod()` is marked `extern` so I can't see how exactly it works to reverse-engineer it without the wrapping. Is there any way to get this type constructed?

Comment: `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` may work.

Comment: @thehennyy It did, incredible! If you want to write that up into a short answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Normally you could just try/catch it and the object will have been constructed, even though the exception was thrown.". If an exception gets thrown by a constructor, no object is created, regardless of if you created it via reflection or `new`...

Comment: Why on earth is this type even declared in such a backward manner? Is it specifically designed *not* to be constructed? Then why are you trying to do so? What is the use-case for this scenario?

Comment: Why do you want to create such an object? It's an implementation of the abstract type `Type` used internally by the framework. There is a strong reason for it not being creatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` method can create objects without invoke a constructor:

> Return Type: System.Object
>
> A zeroed object of the specified type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject(v=vs.110).aspx